# OpenCV - homographic conversion on point used for matrix computation does not match

Tags: python, opencv, scale, homography

I have an image taken from a given perspective. It includes a square of size 350mm in real world. I want to click on the image and know the coordinate of the point in real world. I thought I would use homographic transformation to do it.

I identified the square corners on the image (`n_corners_px`), and computed the homography matrix H in OpenCV. Then I reapplied a dot product btw H and my `n_corners_px` points, hoping to find an exact correspondence back with the coordinates of `n_corners_mm` (where `n_corners_mm` are corresponding points in real world). It worked for the origin [0, 0] point, but not for the [350, 350] corner point.

```py
n_corners_px = np.array([[88, 102], [1808, 214], [1834, 1872], [109, 1986]])
n_corners_mm = np.array([[0, 350], [350, 350], [350, 0], [0, 0]])
    
H, _ = cv2.findHomography(n_corners_px, n_corners_mm)
    
np.isclose(np.dot(H,  np.append(n_corners_px[3], 1))[:2], n_corners_mm[3])  # True
np.isclose(np.dot(H,  np.append(n_corners_px[1], 1))[:2], n_corners_mm[1])  # False, left-hand size equals to [306.33, 306.33], NOT [350, 350]
```

It is as if the image was scaled down a bit.

The H matrix I get is:

```
    [[  0.17823,  -0.00199, -15.48154],
     [ -0.0122 ,  -0.18457, 367.88287],
     [ -0.00007,   0.     ,   1.     ]]
```

I checked that the image is straightened properly. `cv2.warpPerspective(img, H, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1])` (where `img` is my original image) shows a square with right angles as intended.

*> what should I do to get my square with the right 350x350 size?*

Comment: your homography is 3x3 matrix, right? You need to extend your point by a 1 as the z entry (homogeneous coordinate). Then multiply that point with the full 3x3 matrix. Divide the result by its z entry. OR: Use opencv's cv2.perspectiveTransform to transform your point-list. If in both cases you don't observe the expected results, please add more information like your actual 3x3 matrix entries and all your points that you used to create that homography,

Comment: Thank you @Micka. H is 3x3 matrix indeed, and in the code above I extend by adding 1 to my original 2D vertor (see `np.append(n_corners_px[i], 1)`). So dividing by the z component is dividing by 1 and should not change anything. I tried the `cv2.perspectiveTransform` and reached the same result. I updated my question to give more details

Comment: After H dot point, the resulting point has already z == 1?

Comment: oh! Got you this time: you meant "dividing by the output z" of course, NOT the input z. You will not be surprised to hear that it solved by discrepancy :D Thank you very much~

Comment: [mre] required. can't tell what code you executed.

Comment: thank you for the reminder @ChristophRackwitz, I updated the question to include a min reproducible example

Comment: you could post an answer for this. then the question-answer form is fulfilled. -- yes, the third dimension *must not* just be sliced off.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Micka solved my problem.

I had to divide the X, Y components of my transformed coordinates (AFTER dot product with homography matrix) by the Z component, which is a scale information:

```py
np_transformed = np.dot(H,  np.append(n_corners_px[1], 1))
np.isclose(np_transformed[:2]/np_transformed[2], n_corners_mm[1])  # True
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).